# Mount rails webrick to serve .php files as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cgi, webrick

I would like to serve php files on my webrick server, as well as load the default rails application. My best option seems to be using php-cgi for that.

I found an implementation for [webrick php handler](https://github.com/questmaster/WEBrickPHPHandler). It works by itself, but I didn't managed to make it work with Rails environment. Apart from the configuration, it seems that I should call at least this line when starting the Webrick:

```
# mount document root again to set new options (add PHPHandler for .php files)
server.mount("/", HTTPServlet::FileHandler, dir,
    {:FancyIndexing => true, :HandlerTable => {"php" => HTTPServlet::PHPHandler}})
```

Is there a way I can add this as a hook or monkey patch to my Rails application? Am I doing it right, or have a super-simple way to achieve that?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There might be a better way to do it using SOA setup instead of putting the app inside another.

Comment: @NoahClark I would like to create a website which you can setup many wordpress installations. The objective is having the smallest bootstrap possible, so instead of for each new site created adding a new site on apache, I thought in host everything with webrick.

Comment: Have you looked at http://mu.wordpress.org ?

Comment: @NoahClark yes, I known that. The point is this is an infrastructure software, in which should be quite easy to create and delete wordpress from many different versions, to test plugins. Using a multisite would keep you stuck with the same version for all wordpresses, correct?

Comment: that is correct. Maybe a better approach would be a production/staging environment.

Comment: @NoahClark Found what I needed, you might want to check my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the best way to run PHP and other CGI scripts on Rails seems to be the [rack-legacy](https://github.com/questmaster/WEBrickPHPHandler) gem. The configuration is simple, and you can set paths to be served as PHP and other CGIs.